# Scriptable telnet client for Windows?

Tags: ssh, script, telnet

I am looking for a telnet client that can send a command, including control codes, such as the sequence below, by pressing a hotkey or clocking a button. Is there a free program that does this? ZOC Term does this, but it is commercial software. I type these commands often, and some automation would be highly appreciated, especially since they are case-sensitive. The commands change depending on the issue/ticket and more than one group of commands could be run on a single system, or else I would use plink.

There are many systems that I login to, and they change daily based on new tickets being opened, and they all have different passwords, so I have to login manually. I need to send a few commands via a script, and then stay logged in to type in further commands. Also, depending on the ticket, the commands would be different. I'm basically looking for Emtec ZOC but in an open source form; it supports different buttons that run different commands. If my need was to create an in-and-out script where the script logs in, issues commands, and logs out, I'd use PuTTY's plink tool.

```
Return CurrentState ^J
```

`^J` in the above example is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: I'm sorry, questions asking for software recommendations are off-topic here, but this is a very nice question, so I believe you could get help at [softwarerecs.se]. For more information on our scope, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: (1) I don’t know whether it will help you, but have you looked at `expect`? (2) I notice that your question is *tagged* [ssh], but “ssh” is not actually mentioned in the question. It’s best to state all your requirements explicitly, and not rely on people looking at the tags.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use a WScript-file,
by making use of SendKeys[1](http://www.antionline.com/showthread.php?264924-Scripting-windows-Telnet), if scripting is allowed.

You can automatically connect to as many hosts as you wish and perform what you want to do without any further interaction.

For more info: [Telnet scripting](http://www.antionline.com/showthread.php?264924-Scripting-windows-Telnet)

Answer (score 1):

It's been years since I've needed to write telnet scripts for Windows systems, but what I used in the past was the free [Telnet Scripting Tool](http://support.moonpoint.com/downloads/windows/network/Telnet/tst10.php), which is a command line program written by Albert Yale. I'm assuming you are using Ctrl-J above to send the [line feed character (LF)](https://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm), i.e., hexadecimal 0A. You can script a carriage return/linefeed (CR/LF) with `\m` when using the tool, which might work for what you need ([instructions on usage](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2008/12/29#telnet_scripting_tool), which will also appear in a window if you run the program with no options). For automating the transmission of text with other [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_characters), you can create a script file, e.g., script.txt and then use the `/r` option for the command to have it run the script, i.e. `tst10.exe /r:script.txt.` You could use a free [hexadecimal editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) such as the [Freeware Hex Editor XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) to create a script file containing whatever strings and control characters, e.g. inserting hex 0A for Ctrl-J, you need to send via Telnet.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that I would like to send  a few commands via the script, and then stay logged in to type in further commands. For an in-and-out script where the script logs in, issues commands, and logs out, I'd use putty's plink tool.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using AutoHotkey along with something, like PuTTY.  AutoHotkey basically includes a built-in programming language, so there's some flexibility.  What I use AutoHotkey for is to automatically run PuTTY and run commands on a certain site.  Once I start my Autohotkey script, I can background PuTTY and do other stuff on the computer, confident that the desired keystrokes will go into the desired program (PuTTY), not just whatever application I have in the foreground at the time.

The downside is that, at this moment, I haven't yet played with it enough to figure out how to read information from the screen.  But for output only (and sleeping), it works well.  It also offers flexibility on what keyboard bindings you like.